# Calculate Jaccard-Index - $size returns value of type string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to calculate the [Jaccard-Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for each document based on a query array.

**Collection**

```
{
  model: Pants,
  colors: [green, blue]
},
{
  model: Trousers,
  colors: [red, blue, yellow]
},
...
```

**Expected Result for query: ['green']**

```
{
  model: Pants,
  jaccard_index: 0.5
},
{
  model: Trousers,
  jaccard_index: 0
},
...
```

**Aggregation pipeline**

```
Query: ['green']

db.clothes.aggregate([
    {'$project': 
        {'model': 1, 
         'colors': 1,
         'colors_intersection': {'$setIntersection': ['$colors', ['green']]}, 
         'colors_union': {'$setUnion': ['$colors', ['green']]}}}, 
    {'$project': 
        {'model': 1, 
         'colors': 1, 
         'intersection_len': {'$size': '$colors_intersection'}, 
         'union_len': {'$size': '$colors_union'} }}, 
    {'$project': 
        {'model': 1, 
         'colors': 1,
         'jaccard_index': {'$divide': ['$intersection_len', 'union_len'] } }}
])
```

**Question 1**

When i perform this query, i get this error message:

> $divide only supports numeric types, not int and string

I guess this means that the operator `$size` returned the calculated Integer as a String, but why?

**Question 2**

Is it possible to merge all three stages and calculate the Jaccard Index in just one projection?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot to add `$` in `"union_len"`... It should be `$union_len`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a break and now it works with the following aggregation:

```
db.clothes.aggregate([
    {'$project': 
        {'model': 1, 
         'jaccard_index':
            { '$divide': [{'$size': {'$setIntersection': ['$colors', ['green']]}},
                          {'$size': {'$setUnion': ['$colors', ['green']]}}] 
            }
        }
    }
])
```